# Apply Masonry on content from Facebook API

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, masonry

I have been trying to implement Masonry into this project for ages now, and I would be totally happy to have someone who can help me out. The internet is full of similar problems with masonry, but none of the given solutions could help me fix this.

Basically, I am pulling reviews from my Facebook page via the Open Graph API with the following code. The Facebook `response` data is converted from json to an array and then stored in the `fb_reviews` variable for later use. This one works as desired:

```
[...]
function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
//convert to array
                    fb_reviews = Object.keys(response).map(function (_) {
                        return response[_];
                    });
//only store needed data of fb_reviews[0]
                    fb_reviews = fb_reviews[0];
                    reviews();
                }
                ;
            });
[...]
```

This works perfectly. As you can see, the following `reviews()` function is called next to display the Facebook data, and this is where I would like masonry to kick in:

```
// DISPLAY REVIEWS
        var print2 = "";
        var reviews = function() {

            var z = fb_reviews.length - 1;
            var print2 = "";
            for (i = 0; i < z; i++) {
//put together div container for every review object
                print2 += '<div class="review" id="review-' + i + '"><div class="meta">' + fb_reviews[i].reviewer.name + ' rated ' + fb_reviews[i].rating + '/5</div><blockquote>' + fb_reviews[i].review_text + '</blockquote></div>';
            }
            print2 = $(print2);

// still works!!!
            $("#reviews").append(print2);

//until here, everything still works, but the following does no longer work:
            $("#reviews").masonry({
                itemSelector: '.review'
            });

        }
        ;
```

The content is appended as desired etc., but I have literally tried any possible way to initialize masonry, including using all snippets I could find for appended content, e. g.:

```
$("#reviews").append( print2).masonry( 'appended', print2 );
```

There are many more, including `reload` and `layout` etc, but this does not make much sense to me, because there is no content in the #reviews-div-container until all Facebook reviews are loaded and appended.

Masonry ALWAYS seems to be called BEFORE the Facebook reviews are appended, no matter where I would position and spread the masonry code snippets.

So what is the best way to get Masonry initialized AFTER the Facebook data is stored and appended?

Thank you so much in advance for your help! Really appreciate your support
Simon

Comment: fairly simple...need to activate plugin within `fb` callback when content does exist

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work either!